# argostranslate translate in while loop crash the code in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, translation

User define Library

```
# filename: my_tr_lib.py

import argostranslate.package
import argostranslate.translate

from_code = "en"
to_code = "ja"

# Download and install Argos Translate package
argostranslate.package.update_package_index()
available_packages = argostranslate.package.get_available_packages()
package_to_install = next(
    filter(
        lambda x: x.from_code == from_code and x.to_code == to_code, available_packages
    )
)
argostranslate.package.install_from_path(package_to_install.download())


def tr(from_text: str) -> str:
    translatedText = argostranslate.translate.translate(from_text, from_code, to_code)
    return (translatedText)
```

Test file  ( Program crash more than 5000 loop in while )

```
import my_tr_lib
# Example: open and read file
line_count=0
while(True):
    print(my_tr_lib.tr("Hello")) # Example: translate file line one by one
    line_count= line_count+ 1
    print(line_count)  # crash program at aprox over the 4000-5000 line count
```

Need to run till the end of the file which is more than aprox 5000 line.

Comment: Crashes with what?

Comment: can not run program for long time after some loop in while the python program stopped automatically without any exceptions.